# Find efficient way of joining tables

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-design, join, relational-database

Here is the problem:
We have 3 tables (MS SQL 2008 R2):

Table 1 FILMS (table with films)

Table 2 Songs (table with songs)

Table 3 Titles

Since “Films” and “Songs” can contain more than one title (I have many titles on different languages), I want to keep all of the titles in the separate table “Titles”. Primary keys in tables Films and Songs are based on [int] identity specification with increment +1.

So for example: we can have a film and song with ID=3.

How can I join table “Titles” with “Films” and “Songs”?

P.S. I tried to create unique keys by adding a new column [idKey] with formula to FILMS an SONGS

for Films it was `(CONVERT([nvarchar](10),[ID],(0))+'f')`

for Songs it was `(CONVERT([nvarchar](10),[ID],(0))+'s')`

where [ID] is their identity specification
But I wasn’t able to mark this column as a primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even if you don't  have foreign key constrain in between this three table, you get the the data by joining three table.

```
 SELECT title.*, film.*,songs.* 
 FROM title t JOIN film f
    ON t.title_name = f.title_name
 JOIN songs s
    ON t.title_name = s.title_name
```

the point is at-least two table should have a general column